# Changing Frametitle style in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am using `imsa` beamer theme. By default the frame title doe not have any shading or box.

[image]

But I want to wrap the `Test` with a box like `tcolorbox` as following
[image]

that should cover the end to end. But when I try

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usetheme{imsa}
\usecolortheme{imsa}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

% Title Page
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{titlebackground.png}}
\frame{
\titlepage
}
% use points template from now on
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{pointbackground.png}}
\small
\begin{frame}{\begin{tcolorbox}
    Test
\end{tcolorbox}}
    


\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

it is not giving what I want.
[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just that the frametitle does not have a background colour, then you can easily add it:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usetheme{imsa}
\usecolortheme{imsa}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red}

\begin{document}


% use points template from now on
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer your `tcolorbox`:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usetheme{imsa}
\usecolortheme{imsa}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}


% use points template from now on
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect soln... Thank you. Do you know how to make the frametitle  a little bit up when using ```tcolorbox```? And a little wide, closer to the left and right mergins

Comment: @TanmoyPati See section "2 Quick Reference" of the tcolorbox manual